# CKEditor5 Custom built with Angular12 or higher

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

if any one can help with below situation.

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular/issues/347

My CKEditor is a .JS file which I plug into angular project.

1. How do I get CKEditor object in angular?
2. How do I use  like tag in angular HTML page if I have built CKEditor using custom build option?

Comment: Have you look in their documentations? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/frameworks/angular.html they have a full documented area for angular...

Comment: Yes I've gone through. Using the same I was able to customize my CKEditor.js build. but challenge now came is to plug in that .JS build file into angular. Angular DOM updates are done by CLI and I have DOM insertion of CKEditor instance in my JS component.